# Amalgam Reaction

Tags: bond

I have some doubt about Amalgams.
On google it says that amalgams are mixtures. However, when I mixed Na and Hg it 'reacted' to form the amalgam. If they are just mixtures, why do they react to form?
Also, two states of Na-Hg form when you reduce the concentration of sodium.
If you take less sodium, is the sodium and Hg completely amalgated or does sodium act as a 'limiting agent'? Also, it is in liqiud form and also is uniform, so I think it is completely amalgated.
Can anyone please explain to me why amalgam is a mixture and not a compound if the above metals react?

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_amalgam) describes amalgams broadly as "*alloys*, *intermetallic compounds*, and *solutions*." All three may apply. Certainly, as "intermetallic compounds", one expects chemical interaction. It is a matter of degree and of definition, as in "polar vs. nonpolar", rather than a simple true/false statement.

For example, "Metallic sodium dissolves in mercury *exothermically*, i.e. with the release of heat... generating sparks [and causing} localised boiling of the mercury." This is more than simple mixing [and **exceedingly** hazardous to the experimenter and environment].

What I find amazing is the mercury can stabilize the ammonium radical, forming [mercury-ammonium amalgam](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1951/jr/jr9510001731), and even [quaternary ammonium amalgams](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1968/df/df9684500187/unauth)!

Comment: Apparently there are a number of phases in the Na-Hg binary system. The OP should look at the phase diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The Hg-Na binary phase diagram is rich in phases. An [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0925-8388(96)02460-7) in the Journal of Alloys and Compounds (Volume 246, Issues 1–2, 15 January 1997, Pages 80-90) shows the many different compositions and crystal structures that may form. The phase diagram given there is (the available pdf is a horrible scan, sorry):

[image: Hg-Na binary phase diagram]

As to why they 'react' - well, those phases are thermodynamically stable, so they would have a lower Gibbs Free Energy compared with the pure Na and Hg phases. At the very least a 'mixture' would have a reduction in $G$ through the entropy of mixing.